# Alternative for JdbcTokenStore in spring security 6

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am doing migration of oauth2 from spring security 4.0.1 to 6.0.1 and found that JdbcTokenStore has been removed in spring security 6
We were previously creating bean of JdbcTokenStore as below:

```
 @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(datastore);
    }
```

I want to keep using my old authorization flow with the same behaviour as the JdbcTokenStore.

Is there any alternative to the same.

Comment: Is this for the OAuth Client or the resource server?

Comment: It is for AuthorizationServer

Comment: could you check for more details [687](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/issues/687) ?